# TypeError at /pet/3/ petAPI() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie to Django and its REST Framework, I am trying to design an API that allows me to perform the basic operations of the CRUD, both the GET, POSt and PUT methods work correctly, however when I try to implement the DELETE method I get a very particular error:

This is my main urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView)
from pethomeApp import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
    path('refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view()),
    path('user/', views.UserCreateView.as_view()),
    path('pet/', views.petView.petAPI),
    path('pet/<int:pk>/', views.petView.petAPI),
]
```

This is my petViwe.py file:

```
from rest_framework import status, views
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.http.response import JsonResponse

from pethomeApp.models import Pet
from pethomeApp.serializers import PetSerializer

# Create your views here.


@csrf_exempt
def petAPI(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if id == 0:
            pets = Pet.objects.all()
            serializer = PetSerializer(pets, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
        else:
            pet = Pet.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = PetSerializer(pet)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = PetSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added successfuly", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to add", safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        pet = Pet.objects.get(id_pet=data['id_pet'])
        serializer = PetSerializer(pet, data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Update successfuly", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to update")
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        pet = Pet.objects.get(id_pet=id)
        pet.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted successfuly", safe=False)
```

And I am trying to test the delete method like this:

[image]

Excuse my ignorance, does anyone have any idea why it takes the DELETE method as GET and does not allow me to delete a record from the database?

Comment: You get a GET request instead of DELETE because well you specified the _wrong_ url. `/pet/3` and `/pet/3/` are not the _same_ (notice the trailing slash). When Django gets a url without a trailing slash it automatically redirects the user to one _with_ the trailing slash (which means a GET request).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the URL parameter is `pk`, not `id`. Indeed, if we look at the path pattern, we see:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('pet/<int:pk>/', views.petView.petAPI),
]
```

You thus should change the signature to:

```
@csrf_exempt
def petAPI(request, pk=0):
    # …
```

and use `pk` instead of `id` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

change the value in url.py

```
path('pet/<int:id>/', views.petView.petAPI),
```

from `pk` to `id`